# AWS Redshift or RDS for a Data warehouse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, data-warehouse

Right now we have an ETL that extracts info from an API, transforms, and Store in one big table in our OLTP database we want to migrate this table to some OLAP solution. This table is only read to do some calculations that we store on our OLTP database.

Which service fits the most here?

We are currently evaluating Redshift but never used the service before. Also, we thought of some snowflake schema(some kind of fact table with dimensions) in an RDS because is intended to store 10GB to 100GB but don't know how much this approach can scale.

Comment: AWS RDS and Aurora databases are OLTP, Redshift is OLAP. I don't know what you mean by "snowflake in an RDS". Snowflake DB is a third-party competitor to Redshift.

Comment: I was thinking more of the Snowflake schema. Like a cube. An example attach https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Emany-Sidi/publication/290787413/figure/fig2/AS:320056861970436@1453318910769/Example-of-Snowflake-Schema.png

Comment: The simple answer is "use a normal database if it works for you, otherwise move to something else such as Redshift". How is a 'normal' database like Amazon RDS PostgreSQL currently insufficient for your needs? Also, if your use-case is just to query a large table occasionally, you might be able to use Amazon Athena to query data stored in Amazon S3, which would be a lot cheaper that using Redshift or RDS. If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which service fits the most here?

imho you could do a PoC to see which service is more feasible for you. It really depends on how much data you have, what queries and what load you plan to execute.

AWS Redshift is intended for OLAP on top of peta- or exa-bytes scale handling heavy parallel workload. RS can as well aggregate data from other data sources (jdbc, s3,..). However RS is not OLTP, it requires more static server overhead and extra skills for managing the deployment.

So without more numbers and use cases one cannot advice anything. Cloud is great that you can try and see what fits you.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful because this was the kind of perspective I need. Do you have any preferences of why not to use RDS database for OLAP?

Comment: @Nemesius you can use RDS for OLAP and me personally I'd start with RDS (create a read replica not to block/load a production DB). I't about scaling options. RDS would handle OLAP up to some level of performance and memory. Maybe it will be good enough for you for long time or even permanently. That's why I say - try it out and see. You can migrate later as requirements grow or not.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Redshift is really great when you only want to read the data from the database. Basically, Redshift in the backend is a column-oriented database that is more suitable for analytics. You can transfer all your existing data to redshift using the AWS DMS. AWS DMS is a service that basically needs your bin logs of the existing database and it will automatically transfer your data we don't have to do anything. From my Personal experience Redshift is really great.

Comment: Redshift doesn't have a Postgres database in the backend. It just uses a Postgres compatible communication protocol so you can connect to it using Postgres drivers.